# Use PHP to display thumbnails as links to images organized in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a folder of images and a MySQL database to manage them. The database has one table: `images`, and 7 fields: `imgID`, `imgTitle`, `imgURL`, `imgDate`, `imgClass`, `imgFamily`, & `imgGender`. The primary key is `imgID` and the Index Key is `imgDate`.

I wish to display thumbnails of these images on a web page as links to the large versions, using the `imgDate` to organize them with newest first, and oldest last. The images have the same file names as their thumbnails. The large images are located in `new_arrivals_img/` relative to the site root, and the thumbnails are located in `new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/` again relative to the site root.

As I'm new to both MySQL and PHP, I was hoping someone could help me with the code. Everything I have tried has failed.

Right now I'm building the site, and thus using MAMP to host it locally. I have had some problem figuring out relative paths for my images. Is there a way to set `new_arrivals_img/` as the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given no code, I think this is what you are looking for

//connect to mysql database

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `imgURL` FROM `images` ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$query) {
 echo "Cannot retrieve information from database.";
} else {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'> <br/>";
 }
}
```

this would show the images with line break from the folder new_arrivals_img/thumbnails

Comment: it came back as "No database selected", hmmmmm

Comment: I added:
`$mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");`   
`mysql_select_db("new_arrivals_imgs") or die("Could not select     database");`
and now it's displaying the thumbnails no problem. Now how do I create links from the thumbnails to open to their larger brethren?

Comment: yes, instead of just echoing the image, wrap em in link tags and the href of the link would be new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."